# httacces redirect parked domain page to main domain page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

i´m in a little trouble, i already have this code on my httacces to redirect a parked domain to a custom folder on main domain, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.parked.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parked.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/custom_folder/ [R=301,L]
```

That works fine.

But, i need to also redirect custom folders/pages from parked domain to main domain, like this:

www.parked.com/custom_folder -> www.maindomain.com/custom_folder/some_thing

And i can´t with that. I tried adding this above code, but everything redirects to first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.parked.com/some_thing[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parked.com/some_thing$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/custom_folder/some_thing [R=301,L]
```

Could someone point me on the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`some_thing` won't be part of `%{HTTP_HOST}`.  It's part of the remainder of the URL.  So instead you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.parked.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parked.com$
RewriteRule ^/some_thing http://www.maindomain.com/custom_folder/some_thing [R=301,L]
```

Also:

1. Make sure that the 2nd block in your question (some_thing -> custom_folder/some_thing) comes *before* the 1st block (/ -> custom_folder) in .htaccess.  Otherwise the first rewrite will take effect and the 2nd won't get a chance to.
2. As it's written, your second block has a syntax error:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.parked.com/some_thing[OR]
   ```

   That's missing a space between `some_thing` and `[OR]`, which will break the condition, if that's really what's in your .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks Andrew... but didn´t work. In fact i have code like you said, no syntax error too.